# I need to determine if two strings about addresses are the same address

Tags: java

北京市东城区安定门西大街26号B310
北京市东城区安定门西大街26号阳光大厦B310室

Although they are different, they are in the same position, how should I determine that these two are the same? It is still a little risky to calculate the similarity of strings.
Thanks！！
My project uses java language, what should I do with it?

Comment: Probably the most correct is to search the address in Google Maps and then compare the GPS coordinates. Although neither free nor foolproof.

Comment: Please tell us what makes these two addresses “the same”. Can the strings be reliably split into parts? If so, how? Please note that site is not a code-writing service. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so please show us your attempt.

Comment: Please define the rules for "same". Any reordering? Different number formats? Spelling? Capitalisation (or other language specific alternatives of representing single symbols)? Also please provide a [mre] of your attempt to check the simplest of those rules. I assume that this is not about "same if a human can interpret and with some thinking and research tell that the same location is meant". To illustrate "Broadway 243, New York" and "you know, that building right across the street from empire state building, the dark grey one, not the steel and glass facade".

Comment: Using deepl.com to understand the two strings ("北京市东城区安定门西大街26号B310" and "北京市东城区安定门西大街26号阳光大厦B310室") it seems that the latter string contains additional words. You could try to define ignorable words and remove them from both strings before comparing.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I then used Here Maps to get the coordinates of the individual addresses with the help of rest requests. Then the longitude and latitude can be compared.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-geocode-brief.html

But you would have to get a free account for that. Additionally you have to evaluate the returned json files. But without an external API I don't think this will work.